Error(Only plan objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed...) while returning Response object
I'm really new to Next.js and have been stuck on this problem for over a day. I want to return plain JSON if the client is shell-based (e.g., cURL, WGET) or requesting JSON data. However, when the Response object is returned, it results in an error:
⨯ Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes are not supported.

Here's the code (/app/[...query]/page.tsx) that causes the problem:
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import ResultView from "./resultview";

interface Params {
  params: {
    query: string[];
  };
}

export default async function Query({ params }: Params) {
  const headersList = headers();
  const userAgent = headersList.get('user-agent');
  const acceptHeader = headersList.get('accept');
  const query = params.query[0];

  if ((acceptHeader && acceptHeader.includes('application/json')) ||
      (userAgent && (userAgent.includes('curl') || userAgent.includes('wget')))) {
    const apiUrl = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/query?query=${query}`;
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
    const data = await response.json();
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(data), {
      status: 200,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    });
  }

  return <ResultView query={query} />;
}


The API (/pages/api/query.ts) is really simple. It just fetches JSON data and responds with it:
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const { query } = req.query;
  let apiUrl = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/${query}`;
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  res.status(200).json(data);
}

Finally, my ResultView component (/app/[...query]/resultview.tsx) looks like this:
'use client';

import { Footer, MyAppBar } from "@/components";
import { useEffect } from "react";

interface ResultViewProps {
  query: string;
}

export default function ResultView({ query }: ResultViewProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (query) {

    }
  }, [query])
  return (
    <>
      <MyAppBar />
      <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-center" style={{ minHeight: 'calc(100vh - 100px)'}}>
        <h1>{query}</h1>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

How can I return plain JSON without causing this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I found the solution. I used the middleware functionality in Next.js. That solved the problem but I still don't understand why code above didn't work.
